# Environment variable PULUMI_CONFIG_PASSPHRASE doesn't appear to be correctly taken by pulumi

Tags: environment-variables, pulumi

When I try to set the PULUMI_CONFIG_PASSPHRASE I get an error, but setting the PULUMI_CONFIG_PASSPHRASE_FILE works:

```
$ PULUMI_CONFIG_PASSPHRASE="REDACTED" pulumi stack output url
error: failed to decrypt: incorrect passphrase, please set PULUMI_CONFIG_PASSPHRASE to the correct passphrase or set PULUMI_CONFIG_PASSPHRASE_FILE to a file containing the passphrase
```

Comment: Can you try this command first - `export PULUMI_CONFIG_PASSPHRASE="REDACTED"`
And then run your pulumi command.

Comment: Hi @ShubhamBansal it didn't work before but I had a few updates in between and it works now. Thanks

Comment: Please update (if you can and remember) the resolution that worked for you. It can help others looking for similar answers in the future.

Answer (score 0):

@ShubhamBansal gave me the right answer, after exporting the environment variable e.g: `export PULUMI_CONFIG_PASSPHRASE="REDACTED"` it works.